# Разбиение числа на цифры независимо от длины

Tags: java, алгоритм

Изучаю java и для практики решаю простенькие логические задачки, типа нахождения счастливого билетика. Часто встречаются задания, где на входе есть n-значное число, и необходимо что-то сделать с цифрами, из которого оно состоит (дан диапазон чисел от 1 до 999, найти, в скольких числах из диапазона встречается цифра 2). Все, что я знаю и умею - это разбивать ни цифры делением:

```
int a = 123 / 100 = 1
int b = 123 / 10 % 10 = 2
int c = 123 % 100
```

Остальная часть задачи проверяется условием. Собственно сам вопрос: **есть ли в java какой либо метод, позволяющий разбивать число на цифры и не привязываться к его длине**? Например, числа, в которых необходимо искать 2 и ммм 13! вводятся с клавиатуры? И длина числа ограничена только типом int.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Разбить число на составляющие\[на Питоне: `digits_recursive()`, `digits_iterative()` функции\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506519/23044)

Comment: int c = 123 % 100
а разве тут не
int c = 123 % 10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Что-то вы сильно мучаетесь с делением. Берите с конца. Взятие остатка от деления **"%"** числа на 10, всегда вам даст последнее из его цифр. И в цикл!

```
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
System.out.println(a);
while(a>0) {
     s.insert(0, a%10);
     a = a / 10;
}
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Причем навскидку, написать данный алгоритм можно не одним способом, выбирайте, кому как нравится:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for(int a=Integer.MAX_VALUE; a>0; a/=10)
         s.insert(0, a%10);
System.out.println(s);
```

Так же вам, и только вам, решать записывать цифры подряд, а в конце переворачивать строку, либо сразу писать все в начало строки.

Comment: Отличный вариант! То, что мне было нужно! Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, можно совсем просто:

```
    int i = 13579;
    String s = ""+i;
    Pri.priln(s.length()+" цифр"+" последняя "+s.charAt(s.length()-1));
```

KISS принцип.

Comment: Согласен, но учебное задание все же. Тем более, что это Java позволяет такую запись, а представление о том, как оно работает должно быть фундаментальным.

Comment: Надеюсь линукс не по такому принципу написан =)

Comment: To @Dex .  Не только Java, на Си можно sprintf()

Comment: @LinuxFan: А что плохого в том, чтобы применить библиотечную реализацию? Думаете, она будет хуже самописной? Вы получаете все десятичные цифры в строке.

Answer (score 2):

Загоняет цифры в список. А дальше делайте, что душе угодно.

```
public static List<Integer> DigitsInNumber(int number) {

    String n = Integer.toString(number);
    char[] charArray = n.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> cia = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0;i<charArray.length; i++){
        int c = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
        cia.add(c);
    }return cia;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю простой цикл.

```
int number = sc.nextInt();
    int number_create;
    if (number<0){ //делаем число положительным
        number *=-1; 
    }
    for (;number>0;number /=10){
        number_create = number%10;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, например.

```
 BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userIn = read.readLine();
    int length = userIn.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int x = Integer.parseInt(userIn.substring(i, (i + 1)));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(number!=0){

    cout<<number%10<<" ";

    num/=10
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    int v = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int h = 0;
    char num[10] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0' };
    int num1[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
    cin >> str;
    char sym;
   
    int* arr = new int[str.length()];
    int* otvet = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        sym = str.at(i); // sym получает значение первого элемента строки

        arr[i] = sym; // задаем в массив каждый эллемент


    }
    while ( v != str.length() )
    {
        


            if (arr[a] == num[h]) // есди эллемент массива совподает с какимто числом из массива с символами мы делаем это
            {
                otvet[b] = num1[h];
                
                b = b + 1;
                a = a + 1;
                v = v + 1;
                h = 0;
            }
            
                h = h + 1;
            

        
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++)
    {
```

Comment: вопрос по java, а не c++