# Разбить число на составляющие

Tags: python, python-2.x, числа

На вход функцией input подается 6-значеное число. Нужно разбить его на на отдельные числа. Например: 123456 -> 1 2 3 4 5 6. Делается это для того, чтобы проверить эквивалентность суммы первой и второй тройки чисел (Задача о счастливом билете). В программировании я начинающий и желательно всё сделать операциями div, mod, if-else

```
a = int(input())
b = a//1000
one = b//100
two = b%11
three = b%10
c = a%1000
four = c//100
five = c%11
six = c%10
if (one+two+three)==(four+five+six):
    print ('Счастливый')
else:
    print ('Обычный')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно, конечно, честно посчитать остатки от деления и т.д., но проще всего разбить на символы строку, а потом перевести эти символы обратно в числа. Делается это во второй строке следующей программы:

```
a = 123456
b = map(int, str(a))
print b
if len(b)==6:
  print "Happy" if b[0] + b[1] + b[2] == b[3] + b[4] + b[5] else "Unhappy"
```

Если очень хочется честным образом делить на 10, то можно вторую строку этой программы заменить на такой фрагмент:

```
b = []
while a > 0:
  b.append(a % 10)
  a = a // 10
b = b[::-1] # так можно развернуть, если бы нам был важен порядок
print b
```

Теперь по тексту Вашей программы: почему-то берётся остаток от деления на 11 (в строках `two = b%11` и `five = c%11`, хотя правильно было бы поделить на 10, а потом взять остаток от деления на 10 (`two = (b // 10) % 10`). Вам надо разобраться, откуда взялось 11, так как это очень странный код.

**Дополнение:**

Если нам важно поддержать случаи входных значений `a` менее, чем шестизначных, то можно поменять всего одну строчку:

```
while len(b) < 6: # теперь в b заведомо будет 6 элементов
```

Также рекомендую изучить код из соседнего ответа (от jfs), так как в нём есть ряд интересных моментов.

Comment: я взял остаток от деления от 11 перебором в консоли, ибо остаток от деления на 10 давал не нужный мне результат, несмотря на верность математики.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за пояснение! Ответ коротко дополнен, рекомендация изучить Ваш ответ добавлена.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы найти сумму цифр числа, заданного в виде строки:

```
def sum_digits(s):
    return sum(map(int, s))
```

это идиоматичный способ для данной задачи в Питоне.

`sum_digits()` функцию можно использовать, чтобы определить является ли заданное число "счастливым":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

s = input() 
middle = len(s) // 2  # середина
if middle == 0 or sum_digits(s[:middle]) == sum_digits(s[-middle:]):
    print('Счастливый')
else:
    print('Обычный')
```

Число считается "счастливым", если сумма цифр левой половины равна сумме цифр правой половины числа. Пустая строка (нет цифр) — в качестве вырожденного случая — также рассматривается "счастливой".

Если хочется, можно использовать деление, чтобы разбить неотрицательное целое число на отдельные цифры:

```
def digits_recursive(n, digits=[]): 
    return digits_recursive(n // 10, [n % 10] + digits) if n else digits or [0]
```

Пример:

```
>>> digits_recursive(123)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Или то же самое, используя явный цикл:

```
def digits_iterative(nonneg):
    digits = []
    while nonneg:
        digits += [nonneg % 10]
        nonneg //= 10
    return digits[::-1] or [0]
```

Пример:

```
>>> digits_iterative(123)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sum(_)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Видел это задание во вводном курсе Python до изучения массивов и функций типа `map()` так что в том случае корректней было вот такое решение.

```
a = int(input())

b = a//1000

one = b // 100
two = b // 10 % 10    
three = b % 10

c = a % 1000

four = c // 100
five = c // 10 % 10
six = c % 10

if (one+two+three)==(four+five+six):
    print ('Счастливый')
else:
    print ('Обычный')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = list('123321')
summ_1 = int(num[0]) + int(num[1]) + int(num[2]) #cумма первых трех
summ_2 = int(num[3]) + int(num[4]) + int(num[5]) #cумма последних трех трех
```

Comment: Добавте немного информации - чем это поможет в решении?

Answer (score 0):

Тут еще прикол в том, что в задаче написано, что вводится строка. И задача решается совсем просто.

```
a = input()
b = int(a[0])+int(a[1])+int(a[2])
c = int(a[3])+int(a[4])+int(a[5])
if c == b:
  print('Счастливый')
else:
  print('Обычный')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input()  # ввод
b = list(n)  # делаем с этого числа список из цифр (они будут сохранятся как текст)
c = [ int(el) for el in b]  # делаем из текста числа для каждого элемента списка (можете в интернете посмотреть генераторы списков)
```

Comment: Строчка `b=list(n)` не нужна, можно сразу `c= [ int(el) for el in b]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
summa = 0
forcha = 0
for i in range(3):
  d = a // (10 ** ((len(str(a)))-1))
  a %= (10 ** ((len(str(a)))-1))
  summa += d
for j in range(3):
  g = a // (10 ** ((len(str(a))) - 1))
  a %= (10 ** ((len(str(a))) - 1))
  forcha += g
if summa == forcha:
 print("Счастливый")
else:
 print("Не счастливый")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если про счастливый билет, то можно так:

```py
is_happy = lambda x: x % 1e3 % 9 == x // 1e3 % 9
```

Тогда можно писать что-то вроде:

```py
is_happy(888978) # True
is_happy(265827) # False
```

Тут не прямое суммирование, а так называемое «корневое число», когда цифры суммируются рекурсивно, пока не останется только одна. Но это работает точно так же.

Если пары не по 3 числа, а по 4, тогда вместо `1e3` пишем `1e4`, если по 2 — соответственно `1e2`, ну и так далее.

Если надо прямо по-русски написать, то ну вот так вот сделайте:

```py
{True: 'Счастливый', False: 'Несчастливый'}[is_happy(235631)]

# Или так, будет выполняться быстрее, но первый вариант читабельнее

is_happy(235631) and 'Счастливый' or 'Несчастливый'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = list(input())
if int(numbers[0]) +int(numbers[1]) + int(numbers[2]) == int(numbers[3])     +int(numbers[4]) + int(numbers[5]):
   print('Счастливый')
else:
    print('Несчастливый')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]