# map() python, разбиение числа на цифры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуй сообщество Stackoverflow)

Все пишут что самым быстрым и удобным разделением числа на цифры есть функция `map()` при таком вызове: `map(int, str(123))` (Вот тут к примеру предложили это решение: [Ссылка на вопрос об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506457/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Далее в том ответе парень обращается к элементам как к списку:

```
print "Happy" if b[0] + b[1] + b[2] == b[3] + b[4] + b[5] else "Unhappy"
```

У меня так не выходит пишет ошибку обращения

```
a = map(int, str(123))
a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Подскажите как поступить? или может я что не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ по ссылке относится к Python2. В версии Python3 функция `map` возвращает не список (как в Python2), а специальный объект одноименного класса `map`. Этот объект итерируемый (т.е. по его элементам можно пройтись с помощью `for`, и вообще можно обращаться как с любым итератором), но обращаться к его элементам по индексу нельзя (о чем и говорит ошибка).

Чтобы получить список цифр, можно явно привести этот объект к списку:

```
digits = list(map(int, str(123)))
print(digits)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(digits[0])  # 1
```

Comment: Ну а как тогда использовать приславутый map() в py3?

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk, пример кода в ответе же.

Comment: Точно завтыкал, спасибо