# Разбить строку на две ровные части

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите как реализовать разбивание строки на 2 части.
Знаю как на символы разбить через split но на 2 ровные части не знаю

Comment: Если количество символов нечетное, то как разбивать?

Comment: @Эникейщик тогда в первую закинуть больше на 1 символ

Comment: связанный вопрос (задача про счастливые билеты): [Разбить число на составляющие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506457/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаем длину строки. В первую часть берем элементы с первого до длина/2, во вторую с длина/2 до последнего:

```
text = "where's my car dude?"
l = len(text) + 1 
part_1 = text[0:l//2]
part_2 = text[l//2:]
print (part_1)
print (part_2)
```

*(добавляем единицу, чтобы в случае нечетного количества символов в первой части было на один символ больше. Если единицу не добавлять, то на один символ больше будет во второй части)*

Результат:

```
where's my
 car dude?
```

Нечетное количество символов:

```
where's my
 car dude
```

Comment: Ай, ну да. И к print скобки добавить.

Comment: А не уточните что вы тут делаете? part_1 = text[0:l//2]
part_2 = text[l//2:]
Именно про [0:   и 2:]

Comment: http://ru.diveintopython.net/odbchelper_list.html Примеры 1.16 и 1.17