# GUI Tkinter создать интерфейс

Tags: python, tkinter

Дополнение на недавний вопрос
[Разбить строку на две ровные части](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805260/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/805268?noredirect=1#comment1273755_805268)
помогите с интерфейсом для этого кода

```
text = "where's my car dude?"
l = len(text) + 1 
part_1 = text[0:l//2]
part_2 = text[l//2:]
print (part_1)
print (part_2)
```

Не обязательно tkinter
Типа ввод строки в поле, кнопка запуска среза и 2 строки что вышли

Comment: Так, и что у вас вызвало затруднения?

Answer (score 0):

Вот то, как я понял, что Вам нужно. Это на скорую руку, можно оптимизировать, но как пример подойдет:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,300)
root.config(bg="lightgray")
root.title("Срез из фраз ")
def slice(self):
    win = Toplevel(root)
    text = ent1.get()
    l = len(text) + 1 
    part_1 = text[0:l//2]
    part_2 = text[l//2:]
    win.title("Результат разбивки")
    win.minsize(550,200)

    lab0 = Label(win, text="Часть №1", bg="lightgray", relief="groove")
    lab0.place(x=50,y=10)
    lab1 = Label(win, text="Часть №2", bg="lightgray", relief="groove")
    lab1.place(x=50,y=80)
    lab2 = Label(win, text=part_1, bg="lightgray", relief="groove")
    lab2.place(x=150,y=10)
    lab3 = Label(win, text=part_2, bg="lightgray", relief="groove")
    lab3.place(x=150,y=80)

    button1 = Button(win,text="Закрыть", command=win.destroy)
    button1.place(x=470, y=160)

lab1 = Label(root, text="Введите свою фразу", bg="lightgray", relief="groove")
lab1.place(x=20,y=10)

ent1 = Entry(root, width=65, bg="lightgreen")
ent1.place(x=50, y=120)

button2 = Button(root, text="Разбить строку",bg="green", height="4", width="15")
button2.place(x=380, y=220)
button2.bind("<Button-1>",slice)

root.mainloop()
```