# Как разбить число на отдельные целые значения?

Tags: python-3.x

```
l = [123456]
```

Необходимо получить числа 1,2,3,4,56

Comment: Почему именно 56?

Comment: Было бы неплохо

Comment: Может быть, но таки почему именно 56?

Comment: на раздельные разбить легко.но по какому критерию получить 56 ? последнее число будет 2х значным ?  или там все двухзначные и строка 0102030456 ?

Comment: Скажите, как разбить на отдельные числа, а с 56 я сам додумаю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506519

Comment: result=[int(x) for x in str(l)] с 56 'сами разбирайтесь'

Answer (score 1):

```
l = 123456
l = list(str(l))
l = list(map(int, l))
# Теперь в l хранится список [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: либо просто `l = list(map(int, str(l)))`

Comment: @timur или [int(n) for n in str(l)]